# Getting time of the freeze frame in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I want to get a time of a freeze frame of a video which is paused by the pause button in WPF. I want to store time of that freeze frame and use it in the future. How do i get a perfect time of that specific frame? What type of variable i should use to store that time?

Comment: Which component are you using to play the video?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use the Position property, which returns a TimeSpan:

XAML

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <MediaElement x:Name="MyMediaElement"
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    LoadedBehavior="Manual"
                    Source="SomeDrive:\SomeFolder\SomeMediaFile.mp4" />
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Width="50"
                Height="50"
                Click="PlayMedia"
                Content="Play" />
        <Button Width="50"
                Height="50"
                Click="PauseMedia"
                Content="Pause" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="MyTextBlock"
                    FontSize="30"
                    Text="0" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Codebehind

```
private void PlayMedia(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyMediaElement.Play();
}

private void PauseMedia(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyMediaElement.Pause();
    var currentTime = MyMediaElement.Position;

    MyTextBlock.Text = currentTime.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are after the `Clock` property of the `MediaElement`.

See the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.clock(v=vs.110).aspx).

You can access the `CurrentTime` property. See [more documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.mediaclock(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried following code.  mePlayer.Pause();
            MediaClock time = new MediaClock();
            time = mePlayer.Clock;
            MessageBox.Show(time.CurrentTime.ToString()); but it's giving me following error 'Error 1 'System.Windows.Media.MediaClock.MediaClock(System.Windows.Media.MediaTimeline)' is inaccessible due to its protection level F:\C# Visual Studio\ProSlide\ProSlide\MainWindow.xaml.cs 180 31 ProSlide
'